# How do I to set dataframe values as y axis values and columns names as y values in matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

The question seems to me quite simple but I haven't found the answer...
Let us have this dataframe:

```
c = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05']

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(5, 5)*100,
    index = list('12345'),
    columns = c
)
df
```

For me the output was:

```
   2019-01-01  2019-01-02  2019-01-03  2019-01-04  2019-01-05

1   96.912858   14.155578   13.979036   25.744212   56.422165
2   37.512717   90.189240   77.083309   67.563723    6.805494
3   12.797403   44.065799   85.259269   26.618987   80.175955
4   72.659555    4.397601   81.203666   72.194170   80.516623
5    9.459955   66.834891   20.604023   89.428701   74.076824
```

So, I need to display plot with dots, or scatter, with columns names values as `x` axis values (this is may days in list `c`), and with `df.values` as values of `y` axis.

Comment: How about: `df.T.plot()`?

Comment: Wouldn't there be lines instead of dots? I'll try

Comment: just do `lw=0` as a hack

Comment: Have you considered setting the index equal to `c`? That is `df.index = c` and then `df.plot.bar()`

Comment: Ok, but if I have shape of dataframe like this (m, n) and `m != n`?